# Solving for $z$ in the complex equation $\sinh z = c$ for particular values of $c$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What values $z$ satisfy

1. $\sinh(z)=-i$, and
2. $\sinh(z)=-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Use the decomposition of $\sinh z$ into real and complex parts. For $z = x + iy$, $x, y$ real, $\sinh$ satisfies
$$\sinh z = \sinh x \cos y + i \cosh x \sin y.$$

In both of your examples, we can solve for $z$ by separately comparing the real and imaginary parts of $\sinh z$ and the given values.

**Edit** For example, the real and imaginary parts of the equation $$\sinh z = -i$$ are
\begin{align}
\sinh x \cos y &=  0  \\
\cosh x \sin y &= -1 .
\end{align}
Now, the first equation holds iff $\sinh x = 0$ or $\cos y = 0$. In the former case, we have $x = 0$, in which case the second equation becomes $\sin y = -1$. In the latter case, we have $y = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, in which case the second equation becomes $(-1)^k \cosh x = -1$. Note that $\cosh x$ is positive for all real $x$.

Comment: I already got the imaginary and real parts. My next question is how can I get the $x$ and $y$ in $z=x+iy$

Comment: Ah, it would have been helpful if you'd specified that in the original question. I'll modify my answer to include a sketch.

Comment: Sir Travis how about the given in number 2?

Comment: It's largely analogous, except now the real and imaginary parts of the constant are $-1$ and $0$, respectively, instead of the other way around.